# Firebase fuctions error. "projectId must be a string in FirebaseApp.options"

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have followed a tutorial and made a project and when i am trying to run the project using `"npm start"` I am getting below error:

```
node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\component\dist\index.cjs.js:134
                throw e;
                ^

    Error [FirebaseError]: projectId must be a string in FirebaseApp.options
        at new FirestoreError (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:153:28)
        at Function.Firestore.databaseIdFromApp (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:22161:19)
        at new Firestore (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:22035:42)
        at C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:23398:16
        at Component.instanceFactory (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:23373:16)
        at Provider.getOrInitializeService (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\component\dist\index.cjs.js:222:39)
        at Provider.getImmediate (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\component\dist\index.cjs.js:120:33)
        at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\index.node.cjs.js:230:49)
        at FirebaseAppImpl.firebaseAppImpl.<computed> [as firestore] (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\index.node.cjs.js:442:39)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vishnu Reddy\Desktop\FreshPrints\node-express-firebase-main\controllers\ApparelController.js:5:28) {
      code: 'invalid-argument',
      toString: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
```

I have my .env file setup as well:

```
NODE_ENV=production
#express server config

PORT=8080
HOST=localhost
HOST_URL=http://localhost:8080

#firebase database config
export default {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<AUTH_DOMAIN>,
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<STORAGE_bucket>",
    messagingSenderId: "<message_sender_id">,
    appId: "<APP_ID>"
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code? If the `export default` part of `.env` itself?

Comment: Okay I’ll do that. It was not there at all when i faced the error. Added it after watching an answer in the overflow.

Comment: @dharmaraj I have tried the same but got same error.
`NODE_ENV=production
#express server config

PORT=8080
HOST=localhost
HOST_URL=http://localhost:8080

apiKey: "AIzaSyB1ubeKZEllORlt-9JiCGH2ShUJBjD9Eyw",
authDomain: "freshprints-50614.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "8080freshprints-50614",
storageBucket: "freshprints-50614.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "342872984862",
appId: "1:342872984862:web:3032b6b51b7e83a32ecd0f"`